# Program that calculates your wake up time and prints it

Tags: c

Here's my task and below is most of the code I already wrote:

> Write a program that asks user to enter current time in 24 hour format and asks how long you want to sleep. Program then calculates your wake up time and prints it. The program must check that values are entered in correct format and must print an error message if invalid input is entered.
>
> Program must also check that the entered numbers are in valid range (0 - 23 / 0 - 59).
>
> Example:
>
> Enter current time (hh:mm): 21:56
> How long do you want to sleep (h:mm): 8:30
> If you go to bed now you must wake up at 6:26.

SPECIFIC QUESTION:

My code adds the number beyond the 24 hr format, ex: "29 hr".

How can I  test if sum of minutes is greater than 59? So that it can increment hours and subtract 1 hour (60 minutes) from minutes

Finally, how to check if hours is over 23? Therefore it needs to subtract 1 day (24 hours) from hours.

Code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int ValidateTime(int hh, int mm)
{
    int ret = 0;

    if (hh > 24)   ret = 1;
    if (mm > 60)   ret = 1;

    return ret;
}

int main()
{
    char string[100] = { 0 };

    int ret = 0;
    int hour1 = 0, min1 = 0;
    int hour2 = 0, min2 = 0;
    int hour_final = 0, min_final = 0;

    int sum = 0;

    printf("\nEnter the time in \"hh:mm\" format : ");
    fgets(string, 100, stdin);       
    sscanf_s(string, "%d:%d", &hour1, &min1);

    ret = ValidateTime(hour1, min1);
    if (ret)
    {
        printf("\nInvalid Time. Try Again.\n");
    }

    do {
        printf("How long do you want to sleep in \"h:mm\" format: ");
        fgets(string, 100, stdin);
        sscanf_s(string, "%d:%d", &hour2, &min2);
        sum = hour1 + hour2, min1 + min2;

        ret = ValidateTime(hour2, min2);
        if (ret)
        {
            printf("\nInvalid Time. Try Again.\n");
        }

    } while (hour2 < 0);


    printf("If you go to bed now you must wake up at: %d:%d", sum);
    fgets(string, 100, stdin);
    sscanf_s(string, "%d:%d", &sum);
     
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You can use division.  e.g. 70/60 = 1.

Comment: Probably beyond the scope of the homework problem, but remember for the future you cannot do date math like this. When Daylight Savings Time changes you're going to wake up late (or early). In real code, time zone rules must be taken into account.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the division and the modulo:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int x = 29;

    printf("%d days, %d hours\n", x / 24, x % 24);
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
1 days, 5 hours
```

Same for minutes and hours, use 60 in this case:

```
int x = 257;

printf("%d hours, %d minutes\n", x / 60, x % 60);
```

Comment: Thanks. Finally, can you please tell me how to setup the 'alarm' by adding current time + how many hours wish to sleep? I mean I have it at the end of my code but dont know to modify it with your code. Thanks.

Comment: @MarcosSagretti have you read the other answer? it seems that he is just answering to what you are looking for (`mktime`).

Answer (score 1):

[Note: I realize this is homework and not a practical date math problem. I'm giving the date math answer because homework is about learning and date math is tricky.]

> Write a program that asks user to enter current time in 24 hour format and asks how long you want to sleep. Program then calculates your wake up time and prints it.

Because of Daylight Savings Time rules, you cannot simply take the current time, add hours and minutes to it, and produce a time to wake up. If DST changes overnight you will wake up an hour early (or late).

Instead, with only the standard library available, you can convert the current time to an epoch time (number of seconds since Jan 1st, 1970 in GMT), add seconds to that, and then convert that back into local time.

First, turn the current time into the full local date and time on the current day. Use [`time`](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_time.htm) to get the time as an absolute number of seconds regardless of time zones. Then [`localtime_r`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/chrono/localtime) to turn that into a local date and time. (Note: `localtime_r` might be `localtime_s` on your compiler).

```
#include <time.h>

// Get the current time since the epoch
time_t current_time = time(NULL);

// Convert it to the current local date and time.
struct tm start_local;
localtime_r(&current_time, &start_local);

// Set the local date to your given hour and minute.
start_local.tm_hour = hour1;
start_local.tm_min = min1;
```

Then convert that back into epoch time with `mktime`.

```
time_t start_time = mktime(&start_local);
```

Now we safely can do math. `start_time` is in seconds. Convert the hours and minutes to seconds and add them.

```
time_t wake_time = start_time + (hour2 * 60 * 60) + (min2 * 60);
```

And convert that back to a local date time.

```
struct tm wake_local;
localtime_r(&wake_time, &wake_local);
```

For formatting, use [`strftime`](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_strftime.htm) (STRing Format Time).

```
char time_part[10];
strftime(time_part, sizeof(time_part), "%H:%m", &wake_local);
```

Now we need to determine if that time is today or tomorrow or something else.

```
int day_diff = wake_local.tm_yday - start_local.tm_yday;

if( day_diff == 0 ) {
  printf("Wake at %s today.\n", time_part);
}
else if( day_diff == 1 ) {
  printf("Wake at %s tomorrow.\n", time_part)
}
else {
  printf("Wake at %s %d days from now. Are you a bear?\n", time_part, day_diff);
}
```

Note that even that is incomplete, what if you set your alarm on New Year's Eve? You'd need to check the year as well.

---

If this seems like an awful lot of work to do something *apparently* simple: welcome to C. In reality, date math is so complex and error prone you'd use [a datetime library](https://developer.gnome.org/glib/2.66/glib-Date-and-Time-Functions.html) for real, but it's good to be aware of the issues.